# How to loop through a users input using getchar() and check to see if the characters are an alphabet or a digit

Tags: c

Im totally new to programming, I picked up a C manual to learn on my own.  I dont want to use an array as Im trying to practice with getchar(). I want to be able to output an error message if the user enters anything other than a digit or an alphabet. I am also trying to practice the C library function isalpha() and isdigit(). This is what I wrote so far, but my output is not quite right.

***Input 1***: "hello"

***Expected output*** : "valid output"

***Input 2***: "hello5"

***Expected output*** : "valid output"

***Input 3***: "hello!"

***Expected output*** : "invalid output"

But my program returns **"valid input"** for all the three inputs above
Please help a newbie try to learn. I greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    char ch;
    int len;
    int valid;


    printf("Enter a word: ");

    for(length = 0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n'; len++)
    {

        if(isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch))
        {
            valid = 1;          
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 0;
        }

    }
    printf("Input length: %d\n", len);

    if (valid == 1)
    {
        printf("Valid\n");
    }
    if(valid == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. You need to change: `char ch;` --> `int ch;`. A  plain `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned`, depending on the implementation, and an `unsigned char` may not be able to hold the value of `EOF`, which is typically `-1`. Further note that `getchar()` can return `EOF` in some circumstances, so you _must_ check for this to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: check out the isalnum() function in ctype. It seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: `len` is never initialized.  Is this the true code?

Comment: `valid` is not initialized and on an empty line is undefined.  `valid` only reflects the last character accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Few pitfalls:

1st there is a typo for your variable name “length” instead of “len”.

2nd As Mitchel0022 stated, your program will always display “valid” providing the last character entered is valid because you reassign a new value for the variable ‘valid’ on each iteration. but you don’t have to use a ‘break statement  since you need the loop to continue in order to get your length, so stick with your flag.

Now your program should run fine. Copy and paste the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    char ch;
    int len;
    //flag is set true
    int valid = 1;

    printf("Enter a word: \n");

    for(len = 0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n'; len++)
    {
        //change flag if character is not number nor letter
        if(!isalpha(ch) && !isdigit(ch))
        {
            valid = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Input length: %d\n", len);

    if (valid == 1)
    {
        printf("Valid\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment under the question, `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. Further, the `getchar()` function can return `EOF` if the user signals `EOF` from the keyboard, if `stdin` has been redirected to a file stream, or if there is an input error. A `char` may not be able to hold the value of `EOF`, so it must be: `int ch`. To avoid an infinite loop when `EOF` is encountered: `for(len = 0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF; len++) {}`.

Comment: Also note that an input containing no alphanumeric characters (`'\n'` only, when user just presses ENTER) is reported as valid by this code.

Comment: David, there are thousand better ways to write the program. But the guy wants to know why his program is not detecting his definition of invalid. By the way, getchar() return type is int but that doesn’t mean the returned value can’t be assigned to anything other than an int.

The  code below will evaluate to true if you type ‘a’ and press enter. 

    char a = 'a';
    char b = getchar();
    if(a == b){
        printf("They're the same\n");
    }

Comment: You should never assign the result of `getchar()` to a `char`, because this function returns the value of the character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`, or `EOF`. This value may not be representable in a `signed char`, if the returned value is greater than `SCHAR_MAX`. This value may not be representable as an `unsigned char`, if `EOF` is returned. In the above code, since a `char` is likely narrower than an `int`, `ch` will be converted to an `int` in the comparison. But, when the assignment of `EOF` was made to `ch`, assuming `EOF` is `-1`,...

Comment: ...the value was converted to `UCHAR_MAX` (probably 255). This is converted to an `int` in the comparison, so the result of comparing `ch` with `EOF` is: `if (255 == -1)`. That is, this comparison fails when it should succeed, since `EOF` was returned from `getchar()`. The fix is to do the right thing: `int ch`. Further, your code does not even check for `EOF`, and if encountered will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is when checking every character, by toggling valid to 0 and 1 really you are only looking at the last character. What you want to do is for every character as soon as you find one character that is not a digit/alpha character then exit

you can replace your if/else with something like this

```
vlaid = 1; //always assume its valid 
for(int length = 0; (ch = getchar()) != '\n'; length++)
{

    if(!isalnum(ch)) //if not a valid character 
    {
        valid = 0; // string is not valid anymore
        break; // we can exit the loop 
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) `vlaid = 1` --> `valid = 1`. 2) `ch` must be an `int`, and the loop must check for `EOF` to avoid a possible infinite loop. 3) This code will report an input containing only `'\n'`, when the user simply presses ENTER, as valid, yet this input contains no alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I see what you mean! Thanks a ton!